# Why does marking a variable readonly mask the exit status in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm confused by this output:

```
$ readonly foo=`exit 1`
$ echo $?
0
$ bar=`exit 1`
$ echo $?
1
```

Why does the `readonly` make a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readonly` is a function call and is entered after the `exit 1` subshell has finished.

Your script now returns the return value of `readonly`.

A one-liner that retains the return code semantics could be

```
foo=`exit 1` ; RC=$? ; readonly foo ; `exit $RC`
```

Comment: Can you add a section describing how to work around this masking?  I guess that's what OP wants in the first place.  Like: `bar=$(exit 1)` and then as a second command: `readonly bar`.

Comment: I did, although the question could well be interpreted as matter of principle as well.

Comment: As it happens, I was just interested in why there was a difference, though the one-liner is neat. Thanks @FelixFrank!